# How to graph a zoomed in circular segment

Tags: geometry

First, apologies for having forgotten my high school math and terminology. Shame! Shame!

The following equation ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ejzmw8pefu ... does a fine job of graphing a perfect top-left quadrant of a circle:

[image]

With the above formula, I can change the amplitude via `a`, and move it vertically up and down with `v` ... but I still need to move the circle horizontally left/right. My first question is, **how do you do that**?

My goal is to flatten out that curve to varying degrees without it becoming parabolic (parabolas and quadratic equations will begin or end "faster", rather than being perfectly symmetrical along the diagonal). If I can horizontally adjust it, I can sort of mess with the variables to graph the red and yellow (photoshopped) circular curve segments:

[image]

My second question would be, is there a better way of creating these symmetrical curves?

*NOTE: All of this is just to solve for `y` given `x` on a nice curve.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as a request for the family of circular arcs that pass through $(0,0)$ and $(b,b)$ for some $b > 0$.  The center of the family of such circles lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line joining these two points, namely $x + y = b/2$.  If we parametrize the center as $(t, b/2 - t)$, then the radius of the circle satisfies the Pythagorean relationship $$r^2 = t^2 + (b/2 - t)^2,$$ hence the circle has equation $$(x - t)^2 + (y - b/2 + t)^2 = t^2 + (b/2 - t)^2.$$  Equivalently, $$x^2 - 2tx + y^2 + (2t-b)y = 0.$$  Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $t$ yields
$$y = \frac{b - 2t \pm \sqrt{(b-2t)^2 + 4x(2t-x)}}{2}.$$  The choice of sign depends on which portion of circle to plot.  If $t \le 0$, we plot the negative sign corresponding to the lower half of the circle.  If $t \ge b/2$, we plot the positive sign corresponding to the upper half.  If $0 < t < b/2$, we must plot a portion of both halves.

Comment: I think your interpretation is spot on, in that I want the arc to pass through both `(0,0)` and `(b,b)` for `b>0`. I've desmos'd your equation here ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pnsapbldkc ... but it doesn't behave as expected. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Ok I see what I did wrong ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d7r7cclzea ... now moving `t` does exactly what I need. This is beautiful. And I envy your mind. Thank you!

Comment: @neokio You didn't do anything wrong in Desmos; it seems to be a bug with the $\pm$ symbol.  When you changed it to $+ \pm$ it fixed the plot.  Note that you can also plot the equation $x^2 - 2tx + y^2 + (2t-b)y = 0$ directly in Desmos; you do not need to plot the version with the $\pm$ and square root.

Comment: This is a revelation. Thank you!